# PHP to JSON - Why this code doesn't work?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database-connection

I'm not a very expert programmer but for an exam text I have to do an android app that interact with a php server. I read lots of tutorial and examples, but the code I write doesn't work. Could you tell me why?

PHP code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_onceuponatimestories");
  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo("connessione fallita!!".mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    } else {

    $sql= "SELECT * ";
    $sql.="FROM stories";
    //$sql.="WHERE ";
   // echo $sql;
    //echo "<br>";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($result){
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //echo "<br>";
            while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $output = array(htmlspecialchars($e['title']), htmlspecialchars($e['author']));
                //$output = array(htmlspecialchars($e['title']), htmlspecialchars($e['author']));
                //echo json_encode($output);
            }
            //echo(json_encode($ris));
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

?
```

And my java code:

```
 public void getData (View v){
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.onceuponatimestories.altervista.org/viewAnd.php");
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity= null;
            String response = "NADA";
            try {
                HttpResponse httpReponse =httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                httpEntity = httpReponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            //} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
        }
            TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            result.setText(response);;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want this code to do and what does it do instead? What have you tried to solve the problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

You commented out your echo statement so PHP isn't going to give you any text back. Also, you don't assign a value to the $ris variable in your PHP. What do you see when you just navigate to the PHP file in a browser?